# Shorten code.Please help me with shorten the code

Tags: javascript

Please help me with shorten the code.

```
window.onload = function(){
const $button = document.querySelector("#side");
const $button1 = document.querySelector("#sidebar-toggle");
const $wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

$button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $wrapper.classList.toggle("toggled");
});
$button1.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $wrapper.classList.toggle("toggled");
});}
```

I need help to shorten my code, I am new in js.

Comment: `const a = document.querySelector("#side");` etc

Comment: `const q=document.querySelector`

Comment: "Shorten" how? Literally just fewer characters? Use a minifier for that. Or less repetitive code? I note that both of your event handlers do exactly the same thing, what have you considered for how you might avoid writing them twice?

Comment: Yes, T.J.Crowder ,I want  less repetitive.

Comment: `self.onload=_=>{const c=document.querySelector("#wrapper");document.querySelectorAll("#side,#sidebar-toggle").forEach(a=>a.addEventListener("click",e=>{e.preventDefault();c.classList.toggle("toggled");}));};` that's about as short as I can make it

Comment: Declare the function once, then use it in both event handlers. For instance: https://pastebin.com/tvm8VvAp But I wouldn't use the `load` event, it happens very late in the page load and the user may click the button before the handlers are attached. Instead, just put the `script` at the end of the HTML, just before the `</body>` tag, or use `defer` or `type="module"` on the `script` tag (`type="module"` has other benefits as well, but read up on modules before using it).

Comment: @Bravo [This is my best attempt](https://jsbin.com/wivazobagi/edit?js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it less repetitive, you could check this out

```
window.onload = function() {
    const $buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#side, #sidebar-toggle");
    const $wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

    for (var i = 0; i < $buttons.length; i++) {
        $buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            $wrapper.classList.toggle("toggled");
        });
    }
}
```

Use `querySelectorAll()` to get multiple items, then you can use multiple "selectors" as parameter.

You should use class instead of id if you can.

By the way, we usually named variable `$myVariable` when it's a jQuery element, `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` are vanilla JS